# OCUnit Test my app with UINavigationController and UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ocunit

I want to write integration application test to test the full CRUD operations. I have a table view to list all objects. User can click "Add" button to push a new detail view controller to add a new object; They can click on an existing object to push a detail view controller to rename the object; They can also delete the object from the list.

I got excited to try out OCUnit to test my app.  However, I have ran into some weird bugs.  I am using UITabBarController + UINavigationController.  I have more than 3 levels of pushViewController in my UINavigationController.  If I test the code as it is with [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES] , it mostly works with two warnings:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
```

I noticed viewDidAppear isn't called hence the warnings.

Then I try to workaround by changing animated:YES to animated:NO.  The warnings go away.  However, I ran into another bug where viewDidLoad isn't called at all.  So the view doesn't load from the NIB file and all the IB controls are nil.  This wasn't the case if I set animated to YES.

This is the code I use to get a handle of the root view controller in the UINavigationController.

```
app = (MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
rootVC = ((MyViewController*)[[((UINavigationController*)[app.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I manually called this code in my test to simulate a click on the UITableView:

```
[rootVC tableView:rootVC.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:ip];  // push is called inside this
```

So I am stuck either I set animated:YES or animated:NO.  Does anyone successfully use OCUnit to test apps with UINavigationController + UITableView?  If so, could you please share some sample code or your experience?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to test -- whether a particular view controller is pushed or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, for unit tests, don't get your root view controller from your app delegate. The actual root view controller is a singleton, and singletons in unit tests create inter-test dependencies. Instead, have the test set up (and tear down) its own view controller instance.

Certain kinds of tests require the view controller to load its nib — for example, to create the table view. For these tests, call

```
[rootVC view];
```

To test that a view controller is pushed, use a testing subclass of your actual view controller and override `navigationController` to return a mock object you can verify. For example,

```
@interface TestingMyViewController : MyViewController
@property(nonatomic, assign) UINavigationController *mockNavigationController;
@end

@implementation TestingMyViewController

@synthesize mockNavigationController;

- (UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    return mockNavigationController;
}

@end
```

Then have your test create a `TestingMyViewController` and a mock. Set up the mock, and assign it to the testing subclass. Invoke the method you want to test, then verify that the mock navigation controller received the call you expected, with the argument you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Sorry my previous question was misleading.  I actually want to write integration application test.  Kind of like writing Javascript in UIAutomation to test end to end.  Can OCUnit do the job or am I better off switching to UIAutomation in Instruments?

Comment: Ah. For integration tests, I'd use something besides OCUnit or any other unit testing framework. UIAutomation is one approach. Another approach worth investigating is Frank + Cucumber: http://blog.thepete.net/2010/07/frank-automated-acceptance-tests-for.html

Comment: Doing so makes the test pass, but when using the application, view controllers aren't pushed on the navigation controller anymore, even though the navigationController method is still called.

Comment: @ladypada, this unit test approach assumes that a valid navigationController has been set up. Do some debugging to see if that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there anything else I need to do besides initializing my mock navigation controller in init? Also declaring it as "assign" generates the following warning during initialization: privly-ios/privly-ios/ApplicationTypeViewController.m:20:35: Assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable; object will be released after assignment

Comment: @ladypada I don't mean double-check your test. I mean, in real use, is navigationController non-nil?